# How to create an ACF shortcode with Repeater Field in WordPress?

Tags: php, functions, advanced-custom-fields

I want to create a shortcode using ACF Repeater Field and so I've found this code and when I tried to apply it on my website it doesn't work. Am using genesis frame work.

my aim is create a shortcode using ACF Repeater Field and display table in post or page.

Here is my code in functions.php:

```
    function menu_loop () { 

    echo    '<div class="entry-content dishes">';
// check if the repeater field has rows of data
        if( have_rows('menu_sections') ):

            // loop through the rows of data
            while ( have_rows('menu_sections') ) : the_row();

                // display a sub field value

                echo '<h2>' . get_sub_field('section_title') . '</h2>';
                if ( have_rows('sections_items'));?>

                    <table>

                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="ja_name">Name</td>
                                <td class="ja_description">Description</td>
                                <td class="ja_price">Price</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>  

                    <?php while (have_rows('section_items') ): the_row(); ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td><?php the_sub_field('dish_names'); ?></td>
                            <td><?php the_sub_field('dish_description'); ?></td>
                            <td>$ <?php the_sub_field('dish_price'); ?></td>
                        </tr>

                    <?php endwhile;?>

                    </table> <?php 

            endwhile;

         else : 

            // no rows found

        endif; ?></div>
add_shortcode('testimonials', 'menu_loop');
```

Comment: @toscho,  this question was actually the original.  the other one that is on hold was the duplicate.  can you change?

Comment: They are all equally off topic. I don't see why they need special care.

Comment: @toscho this is the original post. please remove duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to return your code when using shortcodes.  Additionally you didn't close the function.

try this:

```php
function menu_loop() {

    $menu = '<div class="entry-content dishes">';

    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
    if (have_rows('menu_sections')):

        // loop through the rows of data
        while (have_rows('menu_sections')) : the_row();

            // display a sub field value

            $menu .= '<h2>' . get_sub_field('section_title') . '</h2>';
            if (have_rows('sections_items')) :

                $menu .= '<table><thead><tr><td class="ja_name">Name</td><td class="ja_description">Description</td><td class="ja_price">Price</td></tr></thead>';

                while (have_rows('section_items')): the_row();
                    $menu .= '<tr><td>' . the_sub_field('dish_names') . '</td><td>' . the_sub_field('dish_description') . '</td><td>$ ' . the_sub_field('dish_price') . '</td></tr>';
                endwhile;

                $menu .= '</table> ';

            else :
                // no rows found
            endif;

        endwhile;

    else :
        //echo 'no rows found';
    endif;

    $menu .= '</div>';
    // Code
    return $menu;
}

add_shortcode('testimonials', 'menu_loop');
```

I just checked your code one more time...
you are echoing the_sub_field on your while statement.  That might mess things up.  Try changing the_sub_field to get_sub_field in your while statement (x3 issues) if the above code places your fields out of place.

Comment: shows syntax error, unexpected '$menu' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ';'

Comment: oops.  missed one of the php closures.  2 lines up from // code.  I'll be at a computer a bit later and test if that doesn't work

Comment: please help me about this code. i found endwhile missed ;. i think

Comment: shows Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Comment: give me a couple minutes

Comment: okay could you try again?  New code posted above doesn't have errors but i don't know how your acf fields are setup.  please note the comment at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: no problem.  could you Mark as answered?

Comment: one more problem arised. i cant find wordpress Toolbar when viewing posts

Comment: what do you mean? could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: this code working fine for me. but i want to sort 'dish_price' subfield data. i my code i replaced dish_price to last_date. how can i sort data help me.